# org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, hibernate, c3p0

Estou tendo problemas de perda de conexão com o banco de dados MySQL, que ocorre após alguns minutos de uso.

Por favor, alguém poderia me ajudar?
Não faço a menor ideia do que pode ser.

Segue meus códigos:

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/**********?useSSL=false</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">123456</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireIncrement">2</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.initialPoolSize">3</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize">2</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize">8</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime">1200</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxConnectionAge">1200</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay">250</property>
```

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    public static Session getSession() {
        return HibernateUtil.getFactory().openSession();
    }

    public static SessionFactory getFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null || sessionFactory.isClosed()) {
            sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory();
        }

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void closeFactory() {
        sessionFactory.close();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(serviceRegistry);
    }

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

            SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            return factory;

        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            System.err.println("FALHA NA CRIACAO DA SESSION FACTORY = " + ex);

            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**O erro**

```
WARN:   SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
ERROR:   Communications link failure
The last packet successfully received from the server was 478,001 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 22,321 milliseconds ago.
Grave:   ==> ERRO ORIGINAL AO EXECUTAR A QUERY: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
Advertência:   StandardWrapperValve[br.com.forcavendasweb.controller.ClientesFVController]: Servlet.service() for servlet br.com.forcavendasweb.controller.ClientesFVController threw exception
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1431)
    at br.com.portalserver.dao.ClienteDAO.listarClientesRepresentante(ClienteDAO.java:109)
    at br.com.forcavendasweb.controller.ClientesFVController.atualizarListaCliente(ClientesFVController.java:261)
    at br.com.forcavendasweb.controller.ClientesFVController.doGet(ClientesFVController.java:100)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet successfully received from the server was 478,001 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 22,321 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3559)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3459)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3900)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2483)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4819)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(NewProxyConnection.java:912)
    at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Operation timed out (Read failed)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:101)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:144)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:174)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3008)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3469)
    ... 47 more
```

**Método DAO onde estourou a excessão**

```
public List<Clientes> listarClientesRepresentante(UsuariosFV usu) {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        Session session;

        List<Clientes> listaCliente = Singleton.getListaCliente();
        String hql = "FROM Clientes WHERE codcli <= 0 AND idemp = :idemp AND codrep = :codrep";

        session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();

            listaCliente = session
                    .createQuery(hql)
                    .setParameter("idemp", usu.getIdemp())
                    .setParameter("codrep", usu.getIdufv())
                    .list();

            if (!transaction.wasCommitted()) {
                transaction.commit();
            }

        } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                try {
                    transaction.rollback();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.err.println("==> ERRO AO FAZER ROLLBACK: " + ex.toString());
                }
            }
            System.err.println("==> ERRO ORIGINAL AO EXECUTAR A QUERY: " + erro.toString());
            throw erro;

        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return listaCliente;
    }
```

Muito obrigado

Comment: Quando você se conecta ao ao banco sem usar o pool C3P0ConnectionProvider, ocorre o mesmo problema?

Comment: Tenta isolar, e se o problema não ocorrer. Pode ser algo relacionado a versão do C3PO, pesquisa se existem problemas relacionados a versão e olha se você está usando a versão mais recente.

Comment: Aqui eu uso a versão 0.9.1.2

Comment: @Bruno Spy A versão do C3P0 é a mesma, 0.9.1.2.  Vou fazer o que você sugeriu e conectar sem o C3P0 e vou ver qual será o comportamento do mesmo.  Retorno com o resultado.  Muito obrigado.

Comment: @Bruno Spy fiz o teste, exclui o C3P0ConnectionProvider e mesmo assim depois de um tempo ele perde a conexão.  infelizmente o erro continua.

Comment: Cade o resto do código? onde esta a Exceção que vc joga e imprimi a msg ´´ERRO ORIGINAL AO EXECUTAR A QUERY´´

Comment: Provável, problema no MySQL, eu tentaria reinstalar. Eu tive um problema parecido com esse, mas o banco era remoto. Muito difícil saber o motivo desse tipo de problema. Acredito que não seja de nível de aplicação.

Comment: @Weslley Barbosa, segue acima o Método DAO onde estourou a excessão.

Comment: @Weslley Barbosa, porém em qualquer parte do código, após alguns minutos parado, a aplicação estoura esta excessão.  O MySQL está parametrizado com timeout de 28000.